# Cross Correlation

Tags: estimation, correlation

I have two signals which I obtained from a State Estimator and the one the measured one "actual signal obtained from the nodes. 
I need to compare between the two signals how similar they are . or if my estimator is good enough. 
what should I do in this case? cross correlation?

Comment: is scaling important to you?  cross-correlation will give you a measure of similarity that is sorta independent of scale.  if scale is important to you, you might measure similarity (or dissimilarity) by subtracting one from the other and squaring (or abs valuing) the difference.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, yes scale is important . measuring the distance you mean using like Manhattan distance or euclidean distance?

Comment: in @msm 's answer below, the square root of #1 is the euclidean distance and #2 (no root) is the Manhattan distance.  in the euclidean case, if either $x[n]$ or $y[n]$ is normalized or scaled to have the same distance from **0** as the other, then the distance from each other will be minimum when their cross-correlation is maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several alternatives:

- You can simply define a form of error and calculate its mean value. The smaller the error is, the closer the signals are. For example:

  1. mean square error (MSE)
     $$e=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N(x[n]-y[n])^2$$
  2. mean absolute error (MAE)
     $$e=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N|x[n]-y[n]|$$
- [Distance metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29) such as Euclidean and Hamming (to see how not similar they are).
- Probabilistic metrics such as correlation coefficient or [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information).

In your specific application, MSE is used very often. There are well-known estimators under MSE criteria. In such case, the estimator is just the conditional mean given the observation. That said, the MSE estimator is generally difficult to find, since it requires calculations based on posterior probabilities. Hence it is generally not derived. Sometimes further constraints (such as linearity) are assumed to make it simpler. They are known as linear minimum mean square error LMMSE estimators under this condition. Wiener filters also follow the same approach.

These are just general topics. In case if you have more details on the specific estimator you are looking at, maybe we could help you more with that.

$$$$